# Не понимаю как ввести и вывести оценки по каждому предмету

Tags: c#

Как ввести оценки ПР: Информатика: 3, 4, 3. Физика: 3, 4, 5. И вывести средний балл по каждому предмету и вывести сведения о тех студентах который средний балл выше 4 и подсчитать их кол-во. Не понимаю почему не выводится "stud.Print();".

```
Console.Write("Введите кол-во студентов: ");
int CountStudents = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Students[] students = new Students[CountStudents];
for (int i = 0; i < CountStudents; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\tВведите информацию о {i + 1} студенте");
    Console.Write("Ф.И.О: ");
    string FullName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Группа: ");
    int ClassRoom = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("\tОценки");
    Console.Write("Информатика: ");
    int Informatics = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read()); Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Физика: ");
    int Physics = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read()); Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("История: ");
    int History = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read()); Console.ReadLine();

    Students stud = new(FullName, ClassRoom, Informatics, Physics, History);
    stud.Print();

}


struct Students
{
    public string FullName;
    public int ClassRoom;
    public int Informatics;
    public int Physics;
    public int History;

    public Students(string FullName, int ClassRoom, int Informatics, int Physics, int History)
    {
        this.FullName = FullName;
        this.ClassRoom = ClassRoom;
        this.Informatics = Informatics;
        this.Physics = Physics;
        this.History = History;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\tВывод \nФ.И.О: {FullName} \nГруппа: {ClassRoom} \nИнформатика: {Informatics} \nФизика: {Physics} \nИстория: {History}");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Students stud = new();` вы не передаете введенные данные в конструктор, просто создаете пустую структуру. Здесь нет никакой магии. Код делает ровно то что вы написали.

Comment: @aepot `Students stud = new(FullName, ClassRoom, Informatics, Physics, History);` поменял, но где должно выводится ПР: Информатика: 3, 4, 3. Выводится 50-51. Почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По порядку

`struct Students` Почему информация об одном студенте называется `Students`? Должно быть `Student`.

Здесь всё делаете правильно

```
int CountStudents = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

А здесь явно что-то пошло не так

```
int Informatics = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read()); Console.ReadLine();
```

Как так вышло? Должно быть

```
int Informatics = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Далее, вы создаете массив

```
Students[] students = new Students[CountStudents];
```

Но нигде его не заполняете. Странно. Зачем вам тогда массив?

```
Students stud = new();
```

Создает пустого студента, и вы сразу же его печатаете и удивляетесь, а почему же он пустой... Тоже странно. Как по-вашему данные попадут в структуру?

Локальные переменные принято кстати в C# называть с маленькой буквы, чтобы не путать с типами, методами и свойствами.

Вот вам код с учетом всех замечаний выше.

```
Console.Write("Введите кол-во студентов: ");
int countStudents = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Student[] students = new Student[countStudents];
for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\tВведите информацию о {i + 1} студенте");
    Console.Write("Ф.И.О: ");
    string fullName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Группа: ");
    int classRoom = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("\tОценки");
    Console.Write("Информатика: ");
    int informatics = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Физика: ");
    int physics = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("История: ");
    int history = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Student student = new Student(fullName, classRoom, informatics, physics, history);
    students[i] = student;
}

for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
{
    students[i].Print();
}
```

```
struct Student
{
    public string FullName;
    public int ClassRoom;
    public int Informatics;
    public int Physics;
    public int History;

    public Student(string fullName, int classRoom, int informatics, int physics, int history)
    {
        FullName = fullName;
        ClassRoom = classRoom;
        Informatics = informatics;
        Physics = physics;
        History = history;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\tВывод \nФ.И.О: {FullName} \nГруппа: {ClassRoom} \nИнформатика: {Informatics} \nФизика: {Physics} \nИстория: {History}");
    }
}
```

Осталось посчитать оценки.

Comment: `int Informatics = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read()); Console.ReadLine();` - Я только так смог писать несколько цифр в одну строку через пробел. Я другого способа не знаю, хотя и этот скорее всего не корректный

Comment: @Noob у вас в структуре у одного студента по одному предмету может быть только одна оценка, то есть одно число. Больше одной оценки вам некуда класть. Каждая оценка по разным предметам задается на новой строке.

Comment: как мне сделать чтобы по каждому предмету я мог вводить несколько чисел и потом вывести средний балл по одному этому предмету?

Comment: @Noob ваш вопрос был `Не понимаю почему не выводится "stud.Print();".` я на него ответил? Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа. Если у вас появился новый вопрос, вы можете задать его отдельно. Иначе мы так до бесконечности будем переписываться.

Comment: на один вопрос ответ был дан, спасибо

Comment: @Noob внимательно поработайте с кодом, который я вам дал, разберитесь, что к чему, и только потом продолжайте. Дам подсказку, вам по каждому предмету нужен массив оценок, типа `public int[] Informatics;`.